# problem reading a file in c

Tags: c, file

This function is supposed to get a file of vectors. The first line
contains the dimension. All other line are in the form of
"P:3,5,2". The letter is P or N and the numbers are coordinates.
This function read a line each time it is being invoked and it saves the P/N char and the
coordinates into an array of double.

```
void readSamplesFile(FILE *sample_p, double result[])
{
    if (dimension == 0)
    {
    fscanf(sample_p,"%lf",&dimension);
    }
    printf("dimentions: %lf\n",dimension);
    printf("LINE \n");
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index<dimension; index++)
    {
        printf("%d",index);
        fscanf(sample_p,"%lf%*[:,]",&result[index]);
        printf("%lf",result[index]);
    }
}
```

when i run it i get an endless loop. the dimension is read correctly but the
it prints

```
LINE 
00.00000010.000000dimentions: 2.000000
```

endlessly. any ideas why? 
hope i was clear

EDIT:
I've added the calling function:

```
void fillArray(FILE *sample_p,FILE *separators_p){
    double coordinates[MAX_DIMENSION];
    while (!feof(sample_p)){
        readSamplesFile(sample_p,coordinates);
    }
}
```

p.s. 
fscanf is set to read : and , but to ignore them.

Comment: Taken alone, this code won't compile. What are definitions for `dimensions` and its cousin `dimention` (in desperate need of a better variable name)?

Comment: its the same variable, i have corrected my spelling here and didn't notice the last one. but in my code its the same one. dimension is just a double

Comment: Check the return value of fscanf

Comment: If it's also printing `LINE` endlessly then the problem is (at least) that you're calling `readSamplesFile` endlessly...

Comment: please post an SSCCE or some more relevant code. I think we all need to know 1)where's defined an initialized dimension variable. 2)there's something printed before "dimentions", where and what is printed? 3)why dimentions isn't simply an integer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/in-c-is-while-feof-always-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Neither 'P' nor 'N' is a valid double, nor are they ':' or ',', so the `fscanf()` fails.  You should always check the return value from `fscanf()`.

We can also debate whether you'd be better off using `fgets()` to read a line and `sscanf()` to parse it.  Doing so avoids some issues; it is the way I'd code it automatically.

---

This code seems to work on the input file:

```
3
P:3,5,2
N:21.12,2.345e6,1.9132e-34
```

yielding the output:

```
dimension: 3.000000
LINE: P:3,5,2
P:offset=2:0=3(2):1=5(4):2=2(6):
LINE: N:21.12,2.345e6,1.9132e-34
N:offset=2:0=21.12(2):1=2.345e+06(8):2=1.9132e-34(16):
```

I'm still not keen on the (mis)use of a floating point `dimension`, but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_DIMENSION = 6 };
enum { MAX_BUFFSIZE  = 4096 };

static double dimension = 0.0;

static int get_dimension(FILE *fin)
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFSIZE];

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin) == 0)
        return -1;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &dimension) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("dimension: %lf\n", dimension);
    return 0;
}

static int readSamplesFile(FILE *sample_p, double result[])
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFSIZE];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sample_p) == 0)
        return -1;
    printf("LINE: %s", buffer);

    char c;
    int offset;
    if (sscanf(buffer, " %c:%n", &c, &offset) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("%c:", c);
    printf("offset=%d:", offset);
    for (int index = 0; index < dimension; index++)
    {
        int newoff;
        if (sscanf(&buffer[offset], "%lf%*[:,]%n", &result[index], &newoff) < 1)
            return -1;
        printf("%d=%g(%d):", index, result[index], offset);
        offset += newoff;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

static void fillArray(FILE *sample_p)
{
    double coordinates[MAX_DIMENSION];
    while (readSamplesFile(sample_p, coordinates) == 0)
        ;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (get_dimension(stdin) == 0)
        fillArray(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `fillArray()` function, as written, does not do anything with the line of data.  There is no checking that the dimension specified is positive and not greater than `MAX_DIMENSION` (that would go in `get_dimension()`).  It feels cleaner to separate `get_dimension()` into a separate function than to hide it inside `readSampleFile()`.  There is an argument that `readSampleFile()` should be renamed `readSampleLine()` since it does only process one line at a time, not a whole file at a time.

The use of the `%n` format specifier is a little tricky, but the code needs to know where to resume reading the buffer on the next cycle.